# $X\mapsto AX-XB$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $F$ be a field, show that $\phi: M_n(F)\ni X\mapsto AX-XB$ is diagonalizable iff $A,B$ are both diagonalizable.

$\Leftarrow$: Let $\xi_i,\eta_j$ be eigenvectors of $A,B$ respectively, with eigenvalues $\lambda,\mu$, then it is easy to show under the base $\xi_i\eta_j'$, $\phi$ has matrix $\lambda_i-\mu_j, 1\leq i,j\leq n$.

$\Rightarrow$: Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: On ⇐ : I think you should have eigenvalues of $\phi$ given by $\lambda_i-\mu_j$. Thus, the matrix of $\phi$ is of size $n^2\times n^2$ with the diagonal entry at $((i,j), (i,j))$ is $\lambda_i-\mu_j$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of $\phi$ in the canonical base of $M_n(F)$ is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}A_{k,i}\delta_{j,l}-\delta_{i,k}B_{l,j}\end{bmatrix}_{(i,j),(k,l)}$$

If this matrix is diagonal then $A_{k,i} = 0$ if $k\neq i$ and $B_{l,j}=0$ if $l\neq j$. Which shows what you are looking for.

Comment: maybe I am misunderstanding - but the linear transformation is necessarily given to have a diagonal representation in the canonical basis. There exists a basis with respect to which $\phi$ is diagonal but we cannot say it's in the standard basis?

Comment: So the OP means diagonalizable instead of diagonal?

Comment: that's what I thought since he phrased it in terms of a linear map. But that would seem to be a harder problem or perhaps even false.

Comment: I do not think it is false. But it will be a little bit harder. I will update my answer then.